# Angular Material mat-datepicker (change) event and format

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I am using angular material datepicker directive and I have few problems.

**1.** When I open date picker dialog and select any date, date shows up in input text box, but I want to call a function when ever any change occur in the input text box.

Right now I am triggering function using (input) directive if I manually enter any value in input text box, and this is working fine as shown in code. I want to trigger same function when the date gets changed using the date picker dialog.

**2.** I also want to change the format of the date from **mm/dd/yyyy** to **dd/mm/yyyy** when selected from date picker dialog. Here mm/dd/yyyy is set by default in this directive.

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="organizationValue" formControlName="organizationValue" (input)="orgValueChange(i)">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="organizationValue"></mat-datepicker-toggle>                 
<mat-datepicker #organizationValue></mat-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

from [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)
you can use one of the below events based on your requirement

```
@Output()
dateChange(): EventEmitter<MatDatepickerInputEvent<D>>
```

Emits when a change event is fired on this .

```
@Output()
dateInput(): EventEmitter<MatDatepickerInputEvent<D>>
```

Emits when an input event is fired on this .

For example:

```
<input matInput #ref [matDatepicker]="organizationValue"
    formControlName="organizationValue" (dateChange)="orgValueChange(ref.value)">
```

or

```
 <input matInput #ref [matDatepicker]="organizationValue"
     formControlName="organizationValue" (dateInput)="orgValueChange(ref.value)">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how to using it in ts file. Should I create these function along with these emitters?

Comment: @UmairJameel `MatDatePicker` provides these events. I have updated my ans

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 12):

1. In your html you can use (ngModelChange)="functionName()" to trigger any function with the change of the date and declare the function in your ts.
2. To change the format of the date :

Add this to `app.module.ts`:

```
import{MatDateFormats, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, NativeDateAdapter, DateAdapter} from '@angular/material';

const MY_DATE_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'input',
        monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short' },
        dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
        monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
    }
 };

export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        if (displayFormat === 'input') {
            const day = date.getDate();
            const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            const year = date.getFullYear();
            return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
        } else {
            return date.toDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

Add the below in providers of `app.module.ts`:

```
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter},  
{provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS}
```

Comment: With regard to the tip on ngChangeControl I think this should be marked as the answer to this question.  I

Comment: I think this is the correct answer to the 2nd question about formatting

Comment: It Works fine in normal mode, but when i build the project in prod mode it throws the error . 'ERROR in : Error: Internal error: unknown identifier {"parse":{"dateInput":{"month":"numeric","year":"numeric","day":"numeric"}},"display":{"dateInput":"input"}}'

Answer (score 10):

HTML:

```
<div class="someClass">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
      <input (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)" formControlName="formControlName" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  public onDateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>): void {
    console.log('Teste', event.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did, Angular 9 :

html:

```
  <input
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    (dateChange)="onDateChange()"
    [(ngModel)]="dateGC"
  />
```

ts:

```
@Output()
dateChange: EventEmitter<MatDatepickerInputEvent<any>> = new EventEmitter();

onDateChange(): void {
    this.dateChange.emit();
}
```

Alternative way of pulling in the Date value into the TS file:

```
export class AppComponent {
  dateGC = new FormControl(new Date());
  //dateGC : any;

  onDateChange(): void {
    console.log("Inside onDateChange()");
    console.log("dateGC= "+ this.dateGC);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a deficiency in the MatDatePicker, so that if you first clear the date (if it has a value), go to another field, then edit the field with manual input (without using the date picker), and leave the field, the month and the day are switched. In order to correct this behaviour, you have to define the "parse" method in addition to the "format" method in the AppDateAdapter class (see the answer of Rak2018):

```
parse(value: any): Date | null {
    const vals = value.split('.'); // or '-' if you use - as separator
    if (vals.length !== 3 || parseInt(vals[2] < 1900) return null;
    return new Date(parseInt(vals[2]), parseInt(vals[1]) - 1, parseInt(vals[0]));
}
```

What I mean by deficiency is that normally, you could define in providers something like

```
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de' }
```

and that works except in the case described above. So the problem is that the default "parse" method does not obey this MAT_DATE_LOCALE setting.

See also [How to implement MD_DATE_FORMATS for datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201050/how-to-implement-md-date-formats-for-datepicker)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. This saved me too.